# Universal App VS2015 Windows Phone Emulator is not Running

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-phone-emulator

I am developing Universal App using VS2015 in Win10. The simulator and the android emulator is running fine.
But when I started the Windows Phone Mobile Emulator, then the emulator runs and shows "OS is starting", and then after a long delay (i.e. 10mins) the Emulator turned off and these messages have been shown.

> 1. Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '8BDF218D-FDBB-4A97-90F9-3AA33B559A92'.': 
>      DeviceException - App deployment failed. Please try again.
> 2. Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. App deployment failed. Please try again.    TestUWP2

What is this Bootstrapping error.
The Emulator in Hyper-V Manager is running fine. Plz help and let me get rid of it.

See the pic.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem here! Found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263576/deploy-universal-app-project-in-vs2015

Comment: So is there any answer from Microsoft or some other professionals, plz share it.

Comment: Not yet, but maybe they will reply in this forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/3f1a4a71-f402-44e9-b18e-f6b2e41796d0/uwpdeployment-fails-on-phone-build-10572?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Do you get any message boxes from the emulator as it is starting?

Comment: I am having the same issue even when deplyong to  an external windows 10 mobile

Comment: See the pics, for msgboxes.
Nothing find yet how to solve this issue, this may be only solve by the Microsoft. Plz get access to them, and get the answer.

Comment: Did you already tried to clean the VM image of the emulator? Just delete it in the hyper-v manager and restart the VS solution in debug, that will recreate the image.

Comment: Plz put the proper procedure, how to delete the VM Images in Hyper-V.
I tried but there's going some thing wrong.

Comment: It's detailed here: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2015/05/fixing-windows-10-emulators-not-showing.html

Comment: Hay! Mr. Depechie thanks for the link, but If u see there, I have commented in details, that I have tried these all things, and nothing get fine.

Then the blogger admin replied a bit, and I reply with other details too. See the comments portion there.

Comment: I had a similar issue with wp8 when there was something funky going on with the emulator images. Give this a go: deploy or debug the app, but after the emulator shows "os is starting..." cancel the build leaving the emulator running. it should eventually load (it might take 30 mins). after this you should be able to deploy successfully. Ultimately you just may need to reinstall the emulators

Comment: I will try this procedure, if it worked, it will be easy and awesome.

Comment: Hello, anyone find solution for that . from many days I suffer from this

Comment: Nothing find yet, and No one can give the perfect answer, even the Professionals too, even posted this quest to social.msdn but didn't find the satisfactory answer. 
The Procedure they provided, I implemented but in vain. Even I lost my all emulators in VS2013 too.

You can check my question and solution on social.msdn via this link. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/58fe69fb-8949-4014-9f6c-e245dc50a994/uwpuniversal-app-vs2015-windows-phone-emulator-is-not-running?forum=wpdevelop

You plz follow this procedure, implement it, if u succeed then share it with us.

Comment: By Installing Update-1 for VS2015, now my Emulators and Simulators both are working fine. Link:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to install latest emulators and Windows SDK, you can get them from this page.

[https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627168))

Its also suggested to update your UWP Tools

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627168

Comment: I already have the latest emulators, I downloaded the file "EmulatorSetup" and then installed, that's y all the emulators shown in vs2015, but the problem was remained same.

Now the other given link regarding UWP Tools Updates, I am trying, if this resolve the issue, then it will be awesome. because this issue has been faced by many developers and couldn't resolve by no one. If this resolve my issue then the +50 repu will be yours.

Comment: I updated the VS15 but in vain, same prob of Bootstrapping.

Comment: By Installing Update-1 for VS2015, now my Emulators and Simulators both are working fine. Link:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Installing the new emulators fixed the issue for me.

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=615095

Comment: By Installing Update-1 for VS2015, now my Emulators and Simulators both are working fine. Link:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: Nope ... didn't work. That link's dead and installing the latest didn't so squat.