# Deploy UWP App Project In VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

In visual studio 2015 I created an UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app,  and try to debug and run it in `Windows 10 Mobile` 5" emulator. But it shows me this error :

*the project app1 needs to be deployed before it can be started.
verify the project is selected to be deployed the solution configuration manager, or deploy it explicitly by clinking one of the deploy commands in the build menu.*

**What is deploy?**
**And how I can deploy my project !?**

Thanks !

Here is the error image:

[image]

Comment: Same problem here! Found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252723/universal-app-vs2015-windows-phone-emulator-is-not-running

Comment: windows mobile 10 emulator works fine but my project did not run in it !! and show that error i have explained up !

Answer (score 15):

Right click on the Solution in Solution Explorer -> Configuration manager...
Check the box in Deploy column in front of you Windows Phone Project

Comment: all of this has been enabled for me by default, I still get the error...

Answer (score 6):

Change Debug **x86**, set Debug **Any CPU** and then right click on your UWP Project and select Deploy (third option, under Rebuild)

Comment: configuring project to Debug X86 ->right click to build->right click to deploy ->debug(F5). You can refer to this for instruction: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn765018.aspx

Comment: what message do you see? the same?

Answer (score 1):

Hello Go to your solution (right Click) and you can see the "Deploy Solution".
[image: See this picture. !]

Comment: I tired but I got this error: Unexpected Error: -2147467259.

Comment: Try to uninstall existing app and then try to deploy the app again via Visual Studio or visit this link: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/327/randomly-cant-deploy-to-device-due-to-unexpected-error-2145615869

Answer (score 0):

I am running Visual Studio in Parallels on a Macbook and also got this error. It turns out my project files were being saved on my mac via network drive. When I moved the entire project to the C:\ drive for my parallels install, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a multi target solution incl. WinPhone and Andorid. The checkbox deploy in the solution configuration was set. How I fixed the problem:

- Set the WinPhone Project as Startup project
- and then select the appropriate deployment device in my case the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

1. Click Build Menu
2. Deploy Selection
3. Hit F5 to start the default/Start-Up project

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click the Solution --> go to Configuration Manager --> check 'deploy' Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was running an SQL File from the from the Projekt separately.
After closing the file it worked again.
The file was in Packages folder in:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\YourApppackegesName
```

Deleting the directory "YourApppackegesName " may also work if closing the File doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

in windows pc
go to 
"Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers"

Right click on your connected windows mobile and remove it.

Retry your project with windows mobile 
It will work